Нужен совет по организации базы данных для телеграм-бота
Всем привет, подскажите, как влияет на нагрузку сервера объем базы данных для бота телеграм? Мне необходима бд, в которой будут хранится индивидуальные значения для каждого пользователя, насколько будет критичным ситуация, если для каждого пользователя будет около 25 трехсимвольных комбинаций (бд состоит из 26 колонок: 1-я - id пользователя, последующие 25 - колонки, содержащие непосредственно трехсимвольные значения)? При этом кол-во пользователей достигает ~50 тысяч?

Ну сгенерируйте такую бд и посмотрите что получится

Такое количество данных в микроскоп не разглядеть.

Объем базы данных на нагрузку сервера не влияет, влияет лишь то, как вы будете осуществлять запросы к этой базе данных, насколько они будут производительны и эффективны.

Если тип столбцов CHAR(3), а у ID — Integer, то получаем 79 байт полезной информации на строку. В зависимости от типа СУБД там может быть ещё несколько байт служебной информации, например, в SQLite будет ещё +26 байт (всего 105 байт на строку).
Умножаем на ~50.000, и получаем меньше 4 мегабайт (в случае со служебной информацией SQLite практически ровно 5 мегабайт). Этот объём запросто хранится в кэше, и для СУБД считается незаметным.

Спасибо большое за ответ, очень помогло)
